# Quoting characters' writing

Tags: quotes

If a character writes something inside of a diary, how do I quote it?  Do I quote just like anything else?  Specifically I am talking about page 145 of the Washington Square Press paperback edition of Warriors Don't Cry.

Comment: I do not understand this question. Do you want to quote something which is written in a novel and in that novel a character has written it into a diary?

Answer (score 1):

The diary entry is part of a the book, is it not? If the section quoted is out of a book in a book, the same author wrote it in the same text as the rest of the book.

Just cite it like you would a normal quote.

You may find this helpful

www.bibme.org

On the off chance that I misread the question the first time, try to phrase your sentences in such a way to avoid quoting quotes.

Not--------->    "Joey looked in his diary. He read "This too doth pass.""

Try this---->    We see, in the scene where Joey is reading his diary, the strange quote "This too doth pass."

I hope this addresses the question, if not, I have no idea.